# Excel copying modules/userforms to new workbook created by macro

Tags: excel, vba

This is a problem I've been trying to tackle for a while. I have a macro that creates a new workbook based off some sheets that have been copied from the Master workbook (named CSJ_Master). However I realized that the modules/userforms were not copied over with it, so when I send the files created by the macro to other people, they are unable to use the macro assigned buttons that I've placed in the workbook. Here's what I've pieced together using a few tutorials online (note: this is code for a userform):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data List")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.ProjectName.Value) = "" Then
Me.ProjectName.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please complete the form"
Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.ProjectName.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ProjectNumber.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.SPVComp.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.Contact.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.ProjMan.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.PODate.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.PONumber.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.PRNumber.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.EstTime.Value


MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"

' Delete any old stray copies of the module1
On Error Resume Next
Kill ("C:\MrXL1.bas")
On Error GoTo 0
' Export Modules
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Array("Module1", "Module2", "Module3", "Module4", "Module5", "Module6", "Module7", "Module8", "Module9", "Module10", "Module11", "Module12", "UserForm1", "Userform2")).Export ("c:\MrXL1.bas")


Sheets(Array("Document Data", "Invoice data", "Hours", "Summary", "Invoice")).Copy
fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Me.ProjectName.Value, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=52

Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import ("c:\MrXL1.bas")


'clear the data
Me.ProjectName.Value = ""
Me.ProjectNumber.Value = ""
Me.SPVComp.Value = ""
Me.Contact.Value = ""
Me.ProjMan.Value = ""
Me.PODate.Value = ""
Me.PONumber.Value = ""
Me.PRNumber.Value = ""
Me.EstTime.Value = ""
Me.ProjectName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

This code is meant to process the data from the userform, then after it's inputted it creates a new workbook, named off the value of ProjName. The code works just fine, except for this section:

```
' Delete any old stray copies of the module1
On Error Resume Next
Kill ("C:\MrXL1.bas")
On Error GoTo 0
' Export Modules
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Array("Module1", "Module2", "Module3", "Module4", "Module5", "Module6", "Module7", "Module8", "Module9", "Module10", "Module11", "Module12", "UserForm1", "Userform2")).Export ("c:\MrXL1.bas")



Sheets(Array("Document Data", "Invoice data", "Hours", "Summary", "Invoice")).Copy
fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Me.ProjectName.Value, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=52

Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import ("c:\MrXL1.bas")
```

This is the main part of the code that copies the sheets and modules/userforms and saves it to a new workbook named off of ProjName. However, I always get Runtime error '13' "Type Mismatch" on this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Array("Module1", "Module2", "Module3", "Module4", "Module5", "Module6", "Module7", "Module8", "Module9", "Module10", "Module11", "Module12", "UserForm1", "Userform2")).Export ("c:\MrXL1.bas")
```

How can I make it so this would work? I'm rather new to VBA and mostly used tutorials to get to this point, so if you could explain in detail, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might find it easier to use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs`, then open that copy and delete the items you *don't* want: everything else will carry over.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the answer! That works as well. One question: how can I make it so the new workbook is opened automatically after it is saved? Right now the original stays open, but I want the new workbook to be opened as well.

Comment: What if I want it to automatically open it...

Comment: I meant "open it from there" using VBA.  `Set newWB = Workbooks.Open(pathToTheSaveAsCopyFile)`

Comment: Ah, my apologies... Thank you very much for the help!